# CSS Flexbox (start,center,end) on fullscreen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I make a CSS Flexbox look like this: [image: desired output]

not like this: [image: actual output]

Mine is not full page, idk why.

Code:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: gray;
  align-self: center;
}

.box:last-child {
  background-color: rgb(182, 179, 179);
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: gray;
  align-self: center;
}

.box:last-child {
  background-color: rgb(182, 179, 179);
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the height of `#outer` is 100% and set `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#outer {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: gray;
  align-self: center;
}

.box:last-child {
  background-color: rgb(182, 179, 179);
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this:

```
#outer{
   height: 100%;
}
```